# An unusual way to count

Tags: number-theory

$p = 2\textbf{k} + c$

or

$p = 2c + \textbf{k}$, where k is always the number in bold

---

2(1) + 0 = 2

2(**1**) + 1 = 3

---

2(**2**) + 1 = 5

2(**3**) + 1 = 7

---

2(**4**) + 3 = 11

2(4) + **5** = 13

2(**6**) + 5 = 17

2(6) + **7** = 19

2(**8**) + 7 = 23

---

> 2(8) + **9** = 25

2(**10**) + 9 = 29

2(10) + **11** = 31

> 2(**12**) + 11 = 35

2(12) + **13** = 37

2(**14**) + 13 = 41

2(14) + **15** = 43

2(**16**) + 15 = 47

---

> 2(16) + **17** = 49

...

You'll notice that 25 and 35 aren't prime. However, you might also notice that each set of primes greater than the square of a prime always adds a new rule to follow in calculating subsequent terms. This is also true from 25 to 48. In this window, if k is even and (k - 2) is divisible by 10 or k is odd and (k + 1) is divisible by 10, it is excluded. This seems arbitrary *until* you write out the rules for subsequent prime square windows.

If we write out the rules for the prime square windows up to 1369, they look like this:

**for even k, exclude if:**

$25 \leq k < 49$ and  $(k - 2) \mod 10 \equiv 0$

$49 \leq k < 121$ and  $(k + 2) \mod 14 \equiv 0$

$121 \leq k < 169$ and  $(k - 4) \mod 22 \equiv 0$

$169 \leq k < 289$ and  $(k + 4) \mod 26 \equiv 0$

$289 \leq k < 361$ and  $(k - 6) \mod 34 \equiv 0$

$361 \leq k < 529$ and  $(k + 6) \mod 38 \equiv 0$

$529 \leq k < 841$ and  $(k - 8) \mod 46 \equiv 0$

$841 \leq k < 961$ and  $(k + 19) \mod 29 \equiv 0$

$961 \leq k < 1369$ and  $(k - 21) \mod 31 \equiv 0$

**for odd k, exclude if:**

$25 \leq k < 49$ and $(k + 1) \mod 10 \equiv 0$

$49 \leq k < 121$ and $(k - 3) \mod 14 \equiv 0$

$121 \leq k < 161$ and $(k + 3) \mod 22 \equiv 0$

$169 \leq k < 289$ and $(k - 5) \mod 26 \equiv 0$

$289 \leq k < 361$ and $(k + 5) \mod 34 \equiv 0$

$361 \leq k < 529$ and $(k - 7) \mod 38 \equiv 0$

$529 \leq k < 841$ and $(k + 7) \mod 46 \equiv 0$

$841 \leq k < 961$ and $(k - 20) \mod 29 \equiv 0$

$961 \leq k < 1369$ and $(k + 20) \mod 31 \equiv 0$

Constructed in this way, the primes appear to have distinct regions marked out by the squares of the primes. Each of these regions has 1 and only 1 rule to add to this sequence. While the structure of the primes is always interesting, I don't quite understand the structure of these rules.

Interestingly, the offsets for odd values of k appears to follow OEIS sequence [A163637](https://oeis.org/A163637)

Complex numbers also make an appearance here in the alternating sign of the offset $i^0$, $i^2$, $i^4$, $i^6$, $i^8$...

Any idea what's going on here?